# Kotlin - Illegal usage of inline parameter callback

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin, inline

I'm converting my `function` having `lambda` as `parameter` into `inline function` for performance improvement.

I have `list` of `lambda` of type `MutableList<(Authenticate) -> Unit>` variable as data member in class. When I try to adding `lambda parameter` into the `list`.

Kotlin compiler says:

> Illegal usage of inline parameter callback

Here is the code

```
// Some code skipped
object Odoo {

    val pendingAuthenticateCallbacks = mutableListOf<(Authenticate) -> Unit>()

    inline fun authenticate(
        login: String, password: String, database: String,
        quick: Boolean = false, crossinline callback: Authenticate.() -> Unit
    ) {
        // Following statement has error saying
        // Illegal usage of inline parameter callback. add 'noinline' modifier to parameter declaration.
        pendingAuthenticateCallbacks += callback
        // Error in above statement

        if (pendingAuthenticateCallbacks.size == 1) {
            // Retrofit2 Object boxing code skipped
            val call = request.authenticate(requestBody)
            call.enqueue(object : Callback<Authenticate> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Authenticate>, t: Throwable) {
                    (pendingAuthenticateCallbacks.size - 1 downTo 0)
                            .map { pendingAuthenticateCallbacks.removeAt(it) }
                            .forEach {
                                it(Authenticate(httpError = HttpError(
                                        Int.MAX_VALUE,
                                        t.message!!
                                )))
                            }
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Authenticate>, response: Response<Authenticate>) {
                    (pendingAuthenticateCallbacks.size - 1 downTo 0)
                            .map { pendingAuthenticateCallbacks.removeAt(it) }
                            .forEach {
                                it(Authenticate(httpError = HttpError(
                                        response.code(),
                                        response.errorBody()!!.string()
                                )))
                            }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Inlining inserts the code in the lambda *directly* into the call site](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html), which removes the overhead of having a function object.

For example, this roughly results in `main` here:

```
fun withLambda(lambda: () -> Unit) {
    lambda()
}

inline fun inlinedLambda(lambda: () -> Unit) {
    lambda()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    withLambda { println("Hello, world") }
    inlinedLambda { println("Hello, world") }
}
```

being converted to this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    withLambda { println("Hello, world") }
    println("Hello, world") // <- Directly inserted!
}
```

If you have

```
pendingAuthenticateCallbacks += callback
```

This is impossible because `callback` must be an object in order for it to be added to the list.

You need to add the `noinline` modifier.

A rough approximation would be to say that an inlined lambda cannot be treated as an object, as it *doesn't really exist* as an object. It is used directly instead of being created as an object.

Of course, you could create a containing lambda:

```
pendingAuthenticateCallbacks += { callback() } // Not a good idea
```

but this would entirely defeat the point of inlining (don't do this!).

However, making the parameter `noinline` would mean your method now has zero lambda parameters that can be inlined, so you might as well just remove the `inline` modifier as performance benefit would be minimal.

The compiler should recognize this:

> Note that if an inline function has no inlinable function parameters and no reified type parameters, the compiler will issue a warning, since inlining such functions is very unlikely to be beneficial.

---

The main reason for inlining methods is for performance *when using lambdas* and for [`reified` generic type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). As of Kotlin 1.1, it is also possible to have an inline property accessor for properties without a backing field.

---

In short, if you have no lambda parameters (or no `reified` type parameters, in which case you *must*), it is usually pointless to mark a function as `inline`.

Comment: Thanks for giving awesome explanation. So, I need to remove `inline` keyword from `function` and add `noinline` keyword to `callback` parameter. right?

Comment: @Ka7Im1011 `noinline` results in a compile error if the function is not `inline`, so you just need to remove the `inline` keyword from the function.

Comment: Sorry Your answer updated. So, I can achieve better performance using `pendingAuthenticateCallbacks += { callback() }` with inline function. right?

Comment: @Ka7Im1011 I meant to add that of an example of what is _possible_. I should clarify this (I will edit it) but no, it would be better to just make the function _not_ `inline`.

Comment: again Thanks for this detailed explanation.