# When lambda parameters must be noinline in Kotlin?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, inline

I often encounter errors in Kotlin inlined functions where lambda parameters must be marked `noinline`.  Other times, lambda parameters seem to work OK.  I've read the Kotlin documentation of [inline functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html), and it seems like this is the operative passage explaining the rule:

> Inlinable lambdas can only be called inside the inline functions or
>   passed as inlinable arguments, but noinline ones can be manipulated in
>   any way we like: stored in fields, passed around etc.

I'm having trouble unpacking those concepts.  Specifically, I'm not sure I fully understand the things I **can't** do (including what all is in the "etc.") with an inlined lambda -- in other words, the things that would disqualify it from being inlined.  **Is there a good reference or more explanation/examples of uses that disqualify a Kotlin lambda parameter from being inlined?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's less of "disqualifying" the lambda from being inlined and more of "this action can't be performed on an inlined lambda."

I kind of answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419811/kotlin-illegal-usage-of-inline-parameter-callback/47420557#47420557).

Inlined methods are directly inserted into the call site, as are any inlined lambdas.

To reuse my old example,

this roughly results in `main` here:

```
fun withLambda(lambda: () -> Unit) {
    lambda()
}

inline fun inlinedLambda(lambda: () -> Unit) {
    lambda()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    withLambda { println("Hello, world") }
    inlinedLambda { println("Hello, world") }
}
```

being converted to this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    withLambda { println("Hello, world") }
    println("Hello, world") // <- Directly inserted!
}
```

What you *cannot* do with an inlined lambda is **treat it like an object**.

This means you cannot store it in a field:

```
val a = lambda // <-- error
```

or call methods on it:

```
lambda.toString() // <-- error
```

because it *is not* an object.

It can also not be passed as an argument to another function

```
func(lambda) // <-- error
```

*unless* the lambda is marked as [`crossinline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns), and the other function's parameter is `inline`.

This is basically stated by the documentation.

> noinline ones can be manipulated in any way we like: stored in fields, passed around etc.

> Note that some inline functions may call the lambdas passed to them as parameters ... To indicate that, the lambda parameter needs to be marked with the crossinline modifier:

Think of inlined lambdas as having their *code* directly inserted into the method. Conceptually they do not actually exist, and "calling" them will just insert their contents into the calling method.

Comment: For me it is working without crossinline, but yea, all what you mentioned working as descripted
inline fun inlined(block: () -> Unit) {
    println("df")
    inlined1(block)
}

inline fun inlined1(block: () -> Unit) {
    println("7")
}